# Nesting in bootstrap 4 on ipad landscape

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have some nested content that is working as should on all screens apart from ipad-landscape. Shouldn't the class triggered on ipad-landscape be col-sm instead of col-lg?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-8 offset-sm-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div>
                    //content
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div>
                    //content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct, it will be lg, and not sm, because--
First lets check the dimensions for ipad, which can be seen in the  responsive tab of the chrome dev tools.
[Responsive tab open in chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXH5X.png)

The dimensions mentioned here for ipad in landscape mode are 1024 x 768, which is 1024 width and 768 height.
Now, moving to [Bootstrap4 Grid Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), as you can see in the table provided there, Large ≥ 992px, which means devices having width more than 992px will get the lg class.

**Note:** All the dimensions mentioned in the boostrap docs are with respect to the width of the page.
My theory behind using width is, because for most websites content needs to be fit data horizontally and vertically it can overflow.